# Set php variable from bash command line

Tags: php, bash, environment-variables

Just to make things easier for me to test while still in the development phase, I was wondering if there was a way that I can set a php variable from the command line before calling my script.

For example, I test out my php scripts by typing:
php scriptname.php

And I look at the output.
However, lets say that scriptname.php contains a variable $myVar that was never set.

Is there a way that I can set this on the command line?

Something like $myVar='foo' php scriptname.php ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to use the [`$_ENV` superglobal](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.environment.php) to pickup environment variables:

```
$var = array_key_exist('env_key', $_ENV) ? $_ENV['env_key'] : 'default';
```

Then run your scripts as follow: `env_key=foo php scriptname.php`.